# Xamarin Forms: Item in listview got disappeared on tapped after scrolling

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a listview with viewcell. I want to switch stacklayout background color on item tapped to make it selected or not. The problem is the item disappears on tapped after scrolling. **Just on tapped after scrolling**

This a GIF that shows the problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-E3rkzwLeuZ6odCmFtfA1roMwrH5tigq/view?usp=sharing

I have tried to remove the items source list and fill it again with but of course didn't work.
I have tried to make *CachingStrategy* all types but background color did changed only on *RetainElement*

Xamarin Forms Version: 4.0.0.425677

**XAML Code**

```
<StackLayout Margin="20" BackgroundColor="White">

        <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lstProducts" ItemTapped="lstProducts_ItemTapped" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}" 
                  CachingStrategy="RetainElement">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{Binding SelectedStateColor}">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding description}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Gray" />
                                </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        </Grid>
        <Button Text="موافق" Clicked="Submit_Clicked" Style="{StaticResource PurpleButton}" Margin="10,0,10,10" />
    </StackLayout>
```

**Product Model**

```
public class Product
{
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Color SelectedStateColor
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsSelected == true)
                    return Color.LightGreen;
                else
                    return Color.White;
            }
        }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ProductsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

private ObservableCollection<Product> _productsList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsList
        {
            get { return _productsList; }
            set { _productsList = value;OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
}
```

**ItemTapped**

```
public class ProductsPage : ContentPage
{

public ProductsPage()
{
BindingContext = new ProductsViewModel();
            InitializeComponent ();

}
ProductsViewModel Context=> (ProductsViewModel)BindingContext;

private void lstProducts_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            Product product = (Product)e.Item;
            product.IsSelected = !product.IsSelected;


            Context.ProductsList[Context.ProductsList.IndexOf(product)] = product;
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi , you can update Xamarin Forms to the latest version (*4.2.0.848062*), then have a try. And do you run it in IOS device, whether it occurs ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am so stupid. Just updating xamarin forms to 4.2.0.709249 fixed the problem. Sorry my mistake

Comment: Glad it works , sometimes the solution is too unbelievable , we are all experienced like this . You can update it in Answer , then will be helpful for other people to know the solution *.^